# How to give user defined values to Weblist which has "select" option by default

Tags: qtp

Can somebody tell me, How to give user specified values to Weblist(It is actually a drop down and after recording it just shows "Select" value,and if the value is stored in my browser cookie select works) I want to give my user defined value everytime. If i use "Set" option the script doesn't run.

How can i do it.? Please help me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Please suggest some ideas ASAP.

Comment: Can't I use select, to select the value from my parameters file? if so how can i?

Answer (score 2):

Normally you can only `Select` an existing value on an WebList. Hence the `Select` method and not a `Set` method.

You can manipulate the DOM by adding an extra `option` to the list and selecting that option. You can do that through the native operations (that is how it is called by QTP) of the object. You can access native methods (`add` in this example) by `.WebList("myWebList").object.add OptionToAdd`, allthough you need an option object to add.

As an alternative you can also change the `.value` property of an existing `option` to the desired value and selecting that one.